# SQL Server : JOIN Between multiple databases error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I am trying to JOIN two different databases and am getting an error that I have not seen before. The SQL joins the database `PDX_SAP_USER` to `asagdwpdx_prod`.

The strange thing is that in the code below, if I exclude the table `dbo.VW.PO_HEADER H` and only include `dbo.VW_PO_ITEM P`, the query works fine, but the JOIN I need is on between the H and G tables. It's when I include the PO Header table the issue arises.

The error message is:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 2
>   Could not find server 'PDX_SAP_USER' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

The SQL code is:

```
SELECT 
    G.order_no, 
    G.order_status, 
    G.cst_order_no,
    H.PO_NUMBER,
    P.PO_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    P.DEL_INDICATOR
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         order_no, 
         order_status, 
         cst_order_no
     FROM 
         asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder1

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         order_no, 
         order_status, 
         cst_order_no
     FROM 
         asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder2

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT 
         order_no, 
         order_status, 
         cst_order_no
     FROM 
         asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder3) G 
JOIN 
    PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW.PO_HEADER H ON G.order_no = H.AHAG_NUMBER
JOIN 
    PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_ITEM P ON H.PO_NUMBER = P.PO_NUMBER 
WHERE 
    G.order_status = '90'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think `PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW.PO_HEADER` is supposed to be `PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_HEADER`. The extra period is making SQL Server think you're using 4-part naming to try to access a linked server.